# Setting correct project CRS and creating vector file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer

I seem to be having difficulties in setting a project CRS in QGIS.
I create a new project, then import a csv points file.  The CRS defaults to WSG 84.  Then I set the layer CRS to British National Grid, and repeat this for the Project CRS.  Then save the project.  Am I doing this right?
When I try to save the points file as a MapInfo tab file (to create a vector file), I get the message that the file could not be created - fault in OGR?

I notice the problem comes to light when I create distance buffers of the points - the distance buffers seem aligned to a WSG 84 projection, they do not look right.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to change the projection of a file is to use Save as from `right-click the layer -> Save as -> Change projection`:

[image]

Then you can create the buffer from the newly created file (with British National Grid CRS). If you want to export it to Mapinfo, you need to select from the Format drop menu list the `Mapinfo TAB`.

Answer (score 1):

> "I create a new project, then import a csv points file. The CRS
>   defaults to WSG 84."

I assume the coordinates in your .csv are in degrees and minutes?

> Then I set the layer CRS to British National Grid

Here is your fault! You can not just set the layer CRS! You have to create a new layer using the way ahmadhanb already pointed out!

> and repeat this for the Project CRS.

Yes, for the Project this is ok.

Comment: Hi, the co-ordinates are BNG Eastings & Northings.

Comment: Interesting, therefore you did everything right!

Comment: Having looked at this issue further, in the Project settings option, CRS, I intend to select 'enable automatic - on the fly', and select BNG, ditto for the CRS for new layers tab.

Comment: discovered where I was going wrong!  Vector file needs to be saved as .SHP - as QGIS can only edit Esri SHP files.  Also need to specify the path correctly where the file is to be saved to.